# Eigen3 matrix multiplication performance

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, visual-studio-2013, eigen

Note: I've posted this also on Eigen forum [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=126975&p=337031#p337031)

I want to premultiply 3xN matrices by a 3x3 matrix, i.e., to transform 3D points, like 
    p_dest = T * p_source

after initializing the matrices:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic> points = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic>::Random(3, NUMCOLS);
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic> dest = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic>(3, NUMCOLS);
int NT = 100;
```

I have evaluated this two versions

```
// eigen direct multiplication
for (int i = 0; i < NT; i++){
  Eigen::Matrix3d T = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
  dest.noalias() = T * points;
}
```

and

```
// col multiplication
for (int i = 0; i < NT; i++){
  Eigen::Matrix3d T = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
  for (int c = 0; c < points.cols(); c++){
    dest.col(c) = T * points.col(c);
  }
}
```

the NT repetition are done just to compute average time

I am surprised the the **column by column** multiplication is about **4/5 time faster** than the direct multiplication
(and the direct multiplication is even slower if I do not use the `.noalias()`, but this is fine since it is doing a temporary copy)
I've tried to change NUMCOLS from 0 to 1000000 and the relation is linear.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and compiling in release

The next figure shows on X the number of columns of the matrix and in Y the avg time for a single operation, in blue the col by col multiplication, in red the matrix multiplication

[image: img]

Any suggestion why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

You're timing the lazy (and therefore lack of) evaluation in the col multiplication version, vs. the lazy (but evaluated) evaluation in the direct version.

### Long answer

Instead of code snippets, let's look at a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). First, "you're" version:

```
void ColMult(Matrix3Xd& dest, Matrix3Xd& points)
{
    Eigen::Matrix3d T = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
    for (int c = 0; c < points.cols(); c++){
        dest.col(c) = T * points.col(c);
    }
}

void EigenDirect(Matrix3Xd& dest, Matrix3Xd& points)
{
    Eigen::Matrix3d T = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
    dest.noalias() = T * points;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int NUMCOLS = 100000 + rand();

    Matrix3Xd points = Matrix3Xd::Random(3, NUMCOLS);
    Matrix3Xd dest   = Matrix3Xd(3, NUMCOLS);
    Matrix3Xd dest2  = Matrix3Xd(3, NUMCOLS);
    int NT = 200;
    // eigen direct multiplication
    auto beg1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < NT; i++)
    {
        EigenDirect(dest, points);
    }
    auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end1-beg1;

    // col multiplication
    auto beg2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < NT; i++)
    {
        ColMult(dest2, points);
    }

    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds2 = end2-beg2;
    std::cout << "Direct time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Col time: " << elapsed_seconds2.count() << "\n";

    std::cout << "Eigen speedup: " << elapsed_seconds2.count() / elapsed_seconds.count() << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With this code (and SSE turned on), I get:

```
Direct time: 0.449301
Col time: 0.10107
Eigen speedup: 0.224949
```

Same 4-5 slowdown you complained of. Why?!?! Before we get to the answer, let's modify the code a bit so that the `dest` matrix is sent to an `ostream`. Add `std::ostream outPut(0);` to the beginning of `main()` and **before** ending the timers add `outPut << dest << "\n\n";` and `outPut << dest2 << "\n\n";`. The `std::ostream outPut(0);` doesn't output anything (I'm pretty sure the badbit is set), but it does cause Eigens `operator<<` to be [called](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a3806d3f42de165878dace160e6aba40a), which forces the evaluation of the matrix.

**NOTE:** if we used `outPut << dest(1,1)` then `dest` would be evaluated only enough to output the single element in the col multiplication method.

We then get

```
Direct time: 0.447298
Col time: 0.681456
Eigen speedup: 1.52349
```

as a result as expected. Note that the Eigen direct method took the exact(ish) same time (meaning the evaluation took place even without the added `ostream`), whereas the col method all of the sudden took much longer.